# mysqldump returns empty file PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I trying to backup my database using mysqldump. The file is being generated but the file is empty. How can I fix this?

PHP Code:

```
$dbuser = 'demo';
$dbpass = 'demo';
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'demo';

$filename = __DIR__ . '/backup/'. $dbname . '_'.$date.'.sql';
exec("mysqldump --user={$dbuser} --password={$dbpass} --host={$host} $dbname > {$filename}");
```

Comment: Please force error reporting and displaying to check if there's any error. Add this to top of script to do this: `error_reporting ( E_ALL); ini_set ( "display_errors", "on");`

Comment: @ErnaniAzevedo I added it what do i do next?

Comment: Execute your code again. If there's any error, will be displayed.

Comment: there is no error displaying

Comment: So, try to execute the same at command line, also, check directory permissions and owner. Your PHP script executing owner must have writing permission.

Comment: still no errors i dont know why